# What is up with my gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ok so i installed a gem and then ran script/server and for some reason its still telling me the gem is not installed

```
sudo gem install paypal_adaptive
Successfully installed paypal_adaptive-0.1.0
1 gem installed
matt@macBookPro ~/Sites/somesite[master (Time to Commit)]$ script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Missing these required gems:
 paypal_adaptive  

You're running:
 ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
 rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/matt/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

 Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

then i run gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
...
paypal_adaptive (0.1.0)
...
...
```

Am i missing something...when i type rake gems this is the result

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/rails-authorization-plugin/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
- [R] will_paginate = 2.3.12
- [R] bandsintown 
- [ ] paypal_adaptive 

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

not sure what and empty  [ ] means

Comment: Have you tried `rake gems:install`?

Comment: what does "rake gems" gives you?

Comment: i tried Have you tried rake gems:install and it installs but still same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read on this forum http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163782 (same problem)

have you tried to append  ':lib => path_to_lib' or ':version => xx.xx.xx' on the config.gem line